# How to keep margins only on inside item?

Tags: flutter

I have a gridview builder and I have set margins on it, is there way to keep the gap only on the middle item, instead of first and last one? I dont want extra padding on sides.

[image]

```dart
  Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: TextField()
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    itemCount: 13,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                        height: 40.0,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            Text("${index}")
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gridDelegate`  with mainAxisSpacing and crossAxisSpacing. And no need to use `margin`. Follow the below code

```
 GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 3, crossAxisSpacing: 4, mainAxisSpacing: 4),
```